# ServiceStack implemente CRUD on UserAuth table generated by Authentication

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I'm trying the built-in Authentication of ServiceStack. My approach is '`OrmLiteAuthRepository`' so users' information are stored in Sql Server instead of the default in memory storage. I use Postman to test the endpoints. 
My target is receiving user rows, updating user information, creating users, deleting an user row. Those are the endpoints I found in Postman after importing (I didn't create those endpoints):

```
GET 'http://localhost:47391/api/register',
PUT 'http://localhost:47391/api/json/reply/Register'
POST 'http://localhost:47391/api/json/reply/Register'
```

I tested POST, Sql Server automatically created the tables to store user data. And the data could be written into Sql Server so I have no problem with POST.

But with PUT, isn't it for updating the existing row? I append '`/{id}`' to the end. But it created a new row in the database instead of updating the existing one. How does it work?

With GET, I got no implementation error.

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "NotImplementedException",
    "Message": "Could not find method named Get(Register) or Any(Register) on Service RegisterService",
    "StackTrace": "   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceExec`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, Object requestDto, String requestName)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRequestExec`2.Execute(IRequest requestContext, Object instance, Object request)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.<>c__DisplayClass11.<>c__DisplayClass13.<RegisterServiceExecutor>b__10(IRequest reqCtx, Object req)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.ManagedServiceExec(ServiceExecFn serviceExec, IService service, IRequest request, Object requestDto)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.<>c__DisplayClass11.<RegisterServiceExecutor>b__f(IRequest requestContext, Object dto)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.Execute(Object requestDto, IRequest req)\r\n   at ServiceStack.HostContext.ExecuteService(Object request, IRequest httpReq)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.GetResponse(IRequest request, Object requestDto)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)"
  }
}
```

How to implement it? I assume I consider the user a normal Web Service entity? and create 'UserService', and requests like:

```
[Route("/register")]
public class User : IReturn<UserResponse>
{
...
}
```

BUT there isn't a model class like 'User' due to the tables are created by ServiceStack itself, how to solve this?
Or is there something I am not aware of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

```
Could not find method named Get(Register) or Any(Register) on Service RegisterService
```

Is saying you're trying to call the built-in ServiceStack `Register` Service instead of your Service. But the `Register` Services isn't enabled by default, your AuthFeature likely explicitly enables it, either with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

Or on the AuthFeature:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    IncludeRegistrationService = true
});
```

If you don't want to enable ServiceStack's built-in Register Service you'll need to remove the registration where it's enabled.

If you instead want the Register Service registered at a different path, you can specify a different route with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature {
    AtRestPath = "/servicestack-register"
});
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I actually had Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature()); in AppHost.cs. The POST is working, but got error when trying GET.

Comment: By saying that I mean I would like to use ServiceStack's built-in RegisterService.

Comment: @KEIOKRYSHA There is no GET defined for the Register Service just as the Exception says. Either use a new Route for your Service or change the built-in route.

Comment: What confused me is after I added Authentication and authorization features. Postman gives me those endpoints - GET/OPT/POST/DEL Authenticate, GET/POST/ UnAssignRoles, GET/POST AssignRoles, GET/POST/PUT Register. So I thought they were ready for use.

Comment: @KEIOKRYSHA The Route doesn't limit it to a Verb so it accepts all Verbs but there's only an implementation for POST. Best place to look is the source code for the Service, all the Source Code is on GitHub. Here's the [RegisterService Post](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b425168196d93784c3852480e74b316f920765a9/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs#L74)

Comment: Can I ask an amateur question? I would like to add PUT and GET methods to the RegisterService.cs. But where is it? It is not in my .sln solution. I mean I would like to use the built-in RegisterService but I want to implement GET/PUT on top of it. Thanks.

Comment: @KEIOKRYSHA Where is it? It's in ServiceStack.dll where ServiceStack's built-in Services are defined. Obviously an existing compiled class in a .dll can't be modified, so just ignore ServiceStack's RegisterService and register and use your own Register Service. Copy what code you need from the existing Service linked above. Don't try register/modify both at the same time, it sounds like it's just confusing you.